# How to disable CUA in Swing

Tags: java, swing, keyboard, awt

How do I disable the Common User Access Features in an undecorated Swing window, like when pressing the ALT-Key, some invisible Window-Menu is being focused? That I do not want!

Basically I want to give the ALT-Key by own functionality in my application but pressing ALT causes the invisible TitleBar of the window to be somehow focused. How can I turn that off?

Comment: Instead of an undecorated JFrame, try using a JWindow.

Comment: @VGR How do I set that on a JWindow - it does not support that feature as it seems ...

Comment: All JWindows are undecorated.  There is no need to set anything.

Comment: It works in terms of the ALT-Key ... though it seems that right now no keystrokes are registered and I can not set a title for the window as it is not supported for JWindow ... any hints there?

Comment: Okay, a JWindow is not without hacks focusable, so I dislike that idea ...